# Does the nearby cycle functor commute with the Verdier duality?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

I would be interested to know the answer to the above question  for the constructible bounded derived category on complex analytic or complex algebraic manifolds (or some other context). A reference would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Dimca's "Sheaves in topology" Proposition 4.2.10, the (perverse) nearby and vanishing cycle functors commute non-canonically with the Verdier duality functor if you have field coefficients. For a proof he refers to Brylinski's "Transformations canoniques, dualité projective, théorie de Lefschetz, transformations de Fourier et sommes trigonométriques" which I don't have available.

Comment: What do you mean by perverse nearby cycle? Only on perverse sheaves?

Comment: I mean the version which includes a degree shift of -1 compared to the "naive" definition of nearby and vanishing cycles. With this degree shift the functors send perverse sheaves to perverse sheaves and commute with Verdier duality. Otherwise they just commute with Verdier duality up to a degree shift.